# SSRS filteration on the basis of length of content in the cell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

How can I filter a report on the basis of the number of characters in a cell. E.g I have a column name and I want to show only those names in the report where the length of the name is less than or equal to 6. I tried expression= Name, operator=<=, and Value=lenth(name) but it is not working. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Length (LEN) function to get the character length of a field. The expression would be something like:

```
=LEN(Fields!YourField.Value)
```

Operator: <=

Value: 6

If the length of the field is less than or equal to 6, the text in the field would be displayed, otherwise the data would not be displayed.

Comment: On doing above I got an error " The processing of FilterExpression for the dataset 'DataSet1' cannot be confirmed. Cannot compare data of types System.int32 and System.String. Please check the data type returned by the filter expression"

Comment: Did you change the **TYPE** to **Integer** in the Filter Expression? It's probably set to TEXT.

Comment: I am trying it. I posted a similar question which is more clear can you please have a look and suggest. thanks.